# How to define subclass type of object values strictly in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to define subclass type of object values as following `SHAPE_PARAMS`.
I could set type with type assertion as `<CircleParameter>`, but missing properties could not be linted.

How can I define subclass type strictly?

```js
const Shapes = {
  CIRCLE_A: "CIRCLE_A",
  CIRCLE_B: "CIRCLE_B",
  RECTANGLE_A: "RECTANGLE_A",
} as const;
type Shapes = typeof Shapes[keyof typeof Shapes];

interface ShapeParameter {
  color: string;
}

interface CircleParameter extends ShapeParameter {
  radius: number;
}

interface RectangleParameter extends ShapeParameter {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

const SHAPE_PARAMS: { [key in Shapes]: ShapeParameter } = {
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_A]: <CircleParameter>{
    color: "red",
    radius: 1,
  },
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_B]: <CircleParameter>{
    // color: "blue", <- Missed property cannot be linted.
    radius: 2,
  },
  [Shapes.RECTANGLE_A]: <RectangleParameter>{
    color: "green",
    width: 3,
    // height: 3, <- Missed property cannot be linted.
  },
};
```

Comment: I solve this problem with your answers.
Thank you so much for quick and detail solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `<TypeName>` syntax *asserts* that the object has that type, whereas you want the compiler to *check* that the object has that type.

The best solution is probably to change the type `{ [key in Shapes]: ShapeParameter }` so that it is more specific:

```
type ShapeParameterMap = {
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_A]: CircleParameter,
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_B]: CircleParameter,
  [Shapes.RECTANGLE_A]: RectangleParameter,
}

const SHAPE_PARAMS: ShapeParameterMap = {
  // ...
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-6A4EwADMCZgydT6czd2zufzhaLUJhcPLRErBisQA)

The upside of this is that you can get a more specific type for `SHAPE_PARAMS[k]` when you access it with some `k` of a more specific type.

On the other hand, perhaps this seems like too much code repetition; in that case, you can achieve what you want by writing a trivial utility function which does nothing, but checks the type of its argument:

```
function check<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}

const SHAPE_PARAMS: Record<Shapes, ShapeParameter> = {
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_A]: check<CircleParameter>({
    color: "red",
    radius: 1,
  }),
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_B]: check<CircleParameter>({
    radius: 2,
    // missing property 'color'
  }),
  [Shapes.RECTANGLE_A]: check<RectangleParameter>({
    color: "green",
    width: 3,
    // missing property 'height'
  }),
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygCwIYAcCmEYF4YG8BQMMAwgJIBKxAMgKID6AggFwwBEZltjrANISRWr0AQi3aCuw3v3I1iAFQYA5AOJdmbWQuVr6DaQF8YSTKEhQA3PigBPdPGTpMOW+hAAzB6gwBtANZoNh4wrmjBiN4QALpW+ACWYFBoAE7uSMBoXugACkjJSAC2aEnJePygADYgySzQyQkA5lYG+PGJKWkZJHHJwBVouflFJTBoAB5JYAAmmBE5eYXFKWVE+VNxAK4QLGAbBQBGKc2tCSWdmeRowFBIYA39g4sj45MzWQMLw8sERADucVMoAgdntDskrEQEGg4g0EFAQQcjvgWvh3BswNc4uAYMAocA-AAeeQAPgAFHkGix5ABKKkrGDJYobZJgYzJJrI1pmaDwAASDGy9GyDHIDAAsnAWJdQMkpgS5hgeO9Hl9ksTsPSfAqIAA6DhCRhRFi4q6E4g9PofIZLNWkn5EHEgKo1NiMqbSB0MpDrLYsACMfCIBmpgZgWscGD1EhERpxeLNFoenxtZPtq29m22MAATKGiAB6fMwApxCAQRowFDJEDoZK2GAAckq1Qb-GDofDkR1WkUqnUsZN+IJ0pudyT1pKqf4RGbLtYDUZaDAHod-0BwJgAGY8zBC8XS+W7pXq7X6w2oTC4a2gyHkVYgA)

Answer (score 1):

You could infer expected shape parameter type from key prefix:

```
type ShapeParams = {
  [K in Shapes]: K extends `CIRCLE_${string}` ? CircleParameter : RectangleParameter
}

/**  type ShapeParams is 
  {
    CIRCLE_A: CircleParameter;
    CIRCLE_B: CircleParameter;
    RECTANGLE_A: RectangleParameter;
  }
*/

const SHAPE_PARAMS: ShapeParams = {
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_A]: {
    color: "red",
    radius: 1,
  },
  [Shapes.CIRCLE_B]: { // <- Property 'color' is missing
    // color: "blue",
    radius: 2,
  },
  [Shapes.RECTANGLE_A]: { // <- Property 'height' is missing
    color: "green",
    width: 3,
    // height: 3,
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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)